# Text classification - randomForest. variables in the training data missing in newdata

Tags: r, r-caret, text-classification

I'm completely new to statistical learning etc but have a particular interest in text classification. I was following a lab I found on the topic here: https://cfss.uchicago.edu/text_classification.html#fnref1. Unfortunately the lab ends before the trained model could be used on new data, so I tried to figure out how to complete it myself.

I have my model trained, Im using random forest. When I try to use `predict()` on new data it throws an error: `Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : 
  variables in the training data missing in newdata`

Which in my mind doesn't make sense as the test data is literally a subset of the original data. I *assume* this error has something to do with how I built my model vs the data structure of the test data but I'm honestly not competent enough to figure out how to solve the error or where it is actually even stemming from (though I assume Im making some ridiculous error).

There are other posts with the same error but I think the source of their errors are different to mine, I've tried to find a fix for this all day!

Complete code I'm using below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(caret)
library(tm)

data(USCongress, package = "RTextTools")
test <- congress[1:100, ]
congress <- congress[100:nrow(congress), ]

(congress <- as_tibble(USCongress) %>%
    mutate(text = as.character(text)))
(congress_tokens <- congress %>%
    unnest_tokens(output = word, input = text) %>%
    # remove numbers
    filter(!str_detect(word, "^[0-9]*$")) %>%
    # remove stop words
    anti_join(stop_words) %>%
    # stem the words
    mutate(word = SnowballC::wordStem(word)))
(congress_dtm <- congress_tokens %>%
    # get count of each token in each document
    count(ID, word) %>%
    # create a document-term matrix with all features and tf weighting
    cast_dtm(document = ID, term = word, value = n))
congress_dtm <- removeSparseTerms(congress_dtm, sparse = .99)
congress_rf <- train(x = as.matrix(congress_dtm),
                     y = factor(congress$major),
                     method = "rf",
                     ntree = 200,
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "oob"))
final_predictions <- predict(congress_rf, newdata = test)
```

The last line (`final_predictions <- predict(congress_rf, newdata = test`) is where the error appears, no error messages occur before that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `test` is not a subset of the data that you are fitting the model with (`congress_dtm`). If you create a subset of `congress_dtm`, it does work:

```
#....
congress_dtm <- removeSparseTerms(congress_dtm, sparse = .99)
test <- congress_dtm[100, ]
congress_rf <- train(x = as.matrix(congress_dtm),
                     y = factor(congress$major),
                     method = "rf",
                     ntree = 200,
                     trControl = trainControl(method = "oob"))
final_predictions <- predict(congress_rf, newdata = test)
final_predictions
#> [1] 12
#> Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 99
```

Comment: Excellent, that makes a lot of sense and I'm annoyed at myself for not seeing it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I wish I could vote it up.